RE needs a logo header!
I think RE is ready for a logo header. Does anyone know any good logo designers and/or have any good ideas for a logo?
I'm not a designer, but I like the idea of the OllyDbg style logo (I just whipped this up in paint.net), using the same 'Terminal' font that OllyDbg uses.

Please share any other logo mockups or ideas. Hopefully we can entice a logo designer to donate their efforts and we can provide attribution and recognition for their work.

FYI: when this site is ready to graduate, our designer will put together a custom theme for the entire UI. Don't hesitate to through out ideas now, but remember that the logo should be recognizable at different sizes and ideally be something that can be used in a few different mediums (online, print, t-shirts, etc.)

Looking at other StackExchange sites, it's clear that most of them have very simple logos.
Extending @Mick's idea a bit...


I like that one!


 

Not red and yellow! Please change the colour to blue or grey.

really? then I should try something not BTTF-like, no?
